# Code sign framework via carthage copy-frameworks fails: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Tags: ios, frameworks, codesign, carthage, xcrun

I'm switching my project from CocoaPods to Carthage and I have problem with code signing. Carthage uses `copy-frameworks` to bundle frameworks into *.app file and cut out unnecessary architectures for simulators. Script fails after executing:

`/usr/bin/xcrun codesign --force --sign - --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements`

because of below error:

`Lokalise.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable`

I'm using this [source](https://github.com/lokalise/lokalise-ios-framework) and I realised that structure of this framework is a little bit different than others which I checked.

[image]

FYI: **Frameworks was code sign correctly after installing via CocoaPods.**